# Re-aligning return value from php function in the html

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have am trying to create a simple voting page.  There are a few links on each side and when the user click the up arrow the vote is counted and the vote count value is increased.  Everything works right now except that when the vote is increased the new value appears on top of the upvote arrow (which makes sense since I am echoing the new value).  I have not been able to figure out how to set the updated vote count into the SPAN which should show the vote count.

Here is the code:
**HTML**

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discussion_links WHERE link_side = 'Michigan'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $link_id=$row['link_id'];
    $url=$row['link_url'];
    $title=$row['link_title'];
    $source=$row['link_source'];
    $votes=$row['vote_count'];
?> 
<div class="top-links-wrapper">
    <div class="link-info">
        <a class="link-title" href="http://<?php echo $url ?>"><?php echo $title . "</a>"; ?>
        <p class="link-source"><?php echo $source . "</p>" ?>
    </div>
    <div class="link-vote-wrapper">
        <div class="link-votes">
            <span><?php echo $votes; ?></span>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="vote" id="<?php echo $link_id; ?>" name="up" title="Up vote"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php   
    }
?>
```

I would like to replace the value returned from the PHP function below into the SPAN in the code above.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

if($_POST['id']) {
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $id = mysql_escape_String($id);
    //Verify IP address in Voting_IP table
    $ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where link_id_fk='$id' and ip_add='$ip'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql);

    if($count==0) {
        // Update Vote.
        $sql = "update discussion_links set vote_count=vote_count+1 where link_id='$id'";
        mysql_query( $sql);
        // Insert IP address and Message Id in Voting_IP table.
        $sql_in = "insert into Voting_IP (link_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$id','$ip')";
        mysql_query( $sql_in);
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('You have already voted');</script>";
    }
    $result=mysql_query("select vote_count from discussion_links where link_id='$id'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $up_value=$row['vote_count'];
    echo $up_value;
}
?>
```

This **$up_value** is the one I would like to replace the current vote count in the HTML.

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(function() {
        $j(".vote").click(function() {
            var id = $j(this).attr("id");
            var name = $j(this).attr("name");
            var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
            var parent = $j(this);

            if (name=='up') {
                $j(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="dot.gif" />');
                $j.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "up_vote.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,

                    success: function(html) {
                        parent.html(html);
                    } 
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Thanks and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to do prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks @Brad , do you have a link that you recommend for a quick intro to do queries with PDO?

Comment: Sure, check this one out:  http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Comment: Thanks Brad, have a good weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are returning the appropriate `(int)` total back in the `success` function,
then you should just set the InnerHTML of the span element to that value

It would be convenient if you were to give each `link-votes` element a unique ID and use that id to change the `InnerHTML` of the `span` element. on ajax success

Since you are already associating the **vote_id** with the event handler, then you
could simply add a prefix to the `span` **id** element, and then in the `success` function,
call something like this:

```
       $("#myPrefix"+id).html(html);
```

Comment: so then the last line of my PHP should be `$(".link-votes > span).html(html) = $up_value;`?

Comment: Well with that code every single element with those classes would change. It would be best to use an ID to reference the up-vote count

Comment: Ouch, ok, I definitely do not want them all to change.  So if I set an ID for the SPAN then I would just set that line at the end of my PHP?

Comment: Yes, set an ID for the SPAN, and use the `id` javascript variable you have in your script to find the right span id. and replace the html with the response from ajax.

Comment: I am still having problems with this.  I gave each each an ID of "V"+id.  `<div class="link-votes"><span id="v<?php echo $link_id; ?>"><?php echo $votes; ?></span></div>`.   At the end of the PHP file I was trying to update the HTML with `$("#v"+id).html(html) = $up_value;` but it is not working.  What am I doing wrong?